# What is the best way the user quickly identify a product

Tags: navigation, users, product-design

I am developing a game portal , where the main User 's task is to seek details of the products in a wide displayed list.
First the image of the product is displayed , followed by its title , its price and two buttons : details and shopping.
My doubt is about how to visually enhance products for the User to quickly identify each product and distinguishes of the others, without the information
presented hinder their searches.

[image: Layout]

Comment: Can you clarify the context here?  Is the fact that his is a game portal relevant? Is the actual task "to seek details"? or is seeking the details part of larger action, like selecting, or buying? You make it sound like these users have to find as much information as the can as quickly as possible. Is that what you are asking? Or are you really just asking about to make these products look less similar to each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well as you are having a gaming portal, I suggest:-

1. Arrange them by popularity
2. Try to give an option to the user to compare between 2 games like we can see in the websites which compares different mobile phones.

3.The most important-> While displaying a particular game product- you can put Pro's, Con's and compatibility as the definite items to be displayed at the first look. The other details can follow later after a button click.